# Making boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor non-blocking

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, nonblocking

I've been trying to make a non-blocking TCP server of sorts using tcp::acceptor. I've done this before using BSD sockets and C(++) but unable to set non blocking I/O using boost.

C(++):

```
#ifdef WIN32
  int mode = 1;
  ioctlsocket(Socket, FIONBIO, (u_long FAR *) &mode);
#else
  fcntl(Socket, F_SETFL, fcntl(Socket, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
#endif
```

And I need the equivalent under the TODO:

```
// reuse address

m_Socket.set_option( boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address( true ) );

// TODO: set non blocking

// listen

m_Socket.listen( );
```

Much obliged!

Comment: Simply use acceptor::async_accept() ? Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm actually refactoring old C++ code the *accept()* function (if could be set nonblocking) would fit quite nicely. I tried to avoid async functions due to the entire concept being unfamiliar to me:

```
tcp::socket *CTCPServer :: AsyncAccept( )
{
  tcp::socket *Socket = new tcp::socket( *m_Service );
  m_Socket.async_accept( *Socket, endpoint, boost::bind( &CTCPServer::HandleAccept, this ) );

  return Socket;
}
```

Is something like this possible (it succeeded with *accept()*)? Basically I have a CTCPServer class which listens, if a connection is established, I make a CTCPSocket( io_service *, socket * ) which fails with "Bad file descriptor" (and it's not a problem in the io_service).

My test main:

```
tcp::socket *Socket;
CTCPServer Server( &io_service, 6667 );

while( true )
{
  if( ( Socket = Server.AsyncAccept( ) ) )
  {
    CTCPSocket TCPSocket( &io_service, Socket ); // fails
    TCPSocket.PutBytes( "stack overflow" );
    TCPSocket.DoSend( );
   }
}
```

Tell me if you need more of the, if I can call it, source.

Comment: this should be another question, not an answer to your own question. Please delete it and ask a new question.

Comment: You missed the point of async_accept. @Sam is right, post another question or modify this question, whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Use [async_accept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept.html).